# How to apply multiple parameter expansion in BASH for a single output?

Tags: bash, linux-kernel, redhat, command-substitution, parameter-expansion

`files=("Benjamin Johnson" "Bastin Johnson" "Bagio Johnson")`

`( IFS=','; echo "${files[*]/#/Mr.}"; echo "${files[*]/ /_}" )`

*Expected Result*
**`Mr.Benjamin_Johnson,Mr.Bastin_Johnson,Mr.Bagio_Johnson`**

*Output result:*

> > **`Mr.Benjamin Johnson,Mr.Bagio Johnson,Mr.Bastin Johnson`**
> >
> > **`Benjamin_Johnson,Bagio_Johnson,Bastin_Johnson`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use an intermediate array.

```
( IFS=','; files=("${files[@]/#/Mr.}"); echo "${files[*]/ /_}" )
```

Comment: Thanks @KamilCuk

Answer (score 1):

Or use `printf`

```
$ printf "Mr.%s,Mr.%s,Mr.%s" ${files[@]/ /_}
Mr.Benjamin_Johnson,Mr.Bastin_Johnson,Mr.Bagio_Johnson
```

Or just one `%s`

```
$ printf "Mr.%s," ${files[@]/ /_}
Mr.Benjamin_Johnson,Mr.Bastin_Johnson,Mr.Bagio_Johnson,
```

But that will add last comma, which can be removed like this

```
$ printf -v test "Mr.%s," ${files[@]/ /_}; echo ${test%,}
Mr.Benjamin_Johnson,Mr.Bastin_Johnson,Mr.Bagio_Johnson
```